# Wordpress Multi-Site - Use both domain and subdomain

Tags: wordpress, dns, subdomain

We have a Wordpress multi-site installation set up where the client can create Wordpress sites on the fly. Each site automatically goes under a subdomain (`sub1.example.com`). Now the client has asked us to point another domain name at one of these Wordpress sites so that the site will work the same under the subdomain (`sub1.example.com`) and main domain (`www.anotherdomain.com`). So both `sub1.example.com/about` and `www.anotherdomain.com/about` will pull up the same page. Can this be done without duplicating the site? If so, how?

Comment: I found a solution to this problem using this plugin. http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/